# How to extract specific points from NDSolve solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Consider the following plot of and ODE solution in phase space ( the code is written below). The red curve is the parametric plot of the solution in phase space, and the blue line is a given curve (in this simplified case, a straight line).

[image]

```
f[x_, y_] := -x + 0.1 y + x^2 y; 
g[x_, y_] := 0.5 - 0.1 y - x^2 y; 
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], 
    x[0] == 0.6, y[0] == 1.4}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 300}];
Show[StreamPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0.5, 2}, 
  StreamStyle -> Black],
 ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[x[t]], Evaluate[y[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 ParametricPlot[{0.5, y}, {y, 0.5, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

How can I extract from the solution the intersections of the red curve and the blue line?

i.e, both a list of the position of the intersection and the time between the intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solve `t` for `x[t]==1/2` with `0<t<100`, and plot the points. Here, `rules`gives you  the time, and `points`the intersections:

```
eqs = Flatten@({x[t], y[t]} /. sol);
rules = FindInstance[eqs[[1]] == 1/2 && 0 < t < 100, {t}, 30];
points = DeleteDuplicates[(eqs /. #) & /@ rules];

Show[StreamPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0.5, 2}, 
StreamStyle -> Black], 
ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[x[t]], Evaluate[y[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
ParametricPlot[{0.5, y}, {y, 0.5, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'll accept this answer if it will be generalized to any given curve (not just a line).

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of "30" at the FindInstances command?

Comment: @jarhead See the docs of [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html). And this post is a direct answer to your question, so it would be rude not to accept it, especially that you've already asked another, more general, question.

Comment: @jarhead in a hurry, “30” in `FindInstances` is how many instances you want when solving the equation. If you want more than existing, you will obtain duplicates. On the other hand, as @corey979 says, you look for a solution of a intersecting line, not a general curve. BTW, this curve is closed or open?, in parametric, implicit, or explicit form?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, I accepted your answer, as it adressed the questions, but have a look at a more generalized solution at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172205/finding-intersections-of-ndsolve-solution-with-curves/172209#172209